# RenderUpdates.draw() always returns rects

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using a sprite group class from pygame, specifically `pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates`

The reason I'm using that sprite group class is because it's supposed to return a list of `rect`s that have been modified.

Specifically, the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates) says this about `pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates` draw() method:

> ...This method also returns a list of Rectangular areas on the screen
> that have been changed. The returned changes include areas of the
> screen that have been affected by previous Group.clear() calls.

**My issue**

My issue is that the `draw()` method is returning a list of `rect`s, even when I don't move any sprites (when there is no animation at all).

Isn't the `draw()` method only supposed to return `rect`s that have been changed?

My minimal example is below:

```
    background_group = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()
    character_group = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()

    character_group.clear(screen, bg_surface)

    character_group.update()

    # The issue is below. 
    # I always get a list of rects, even if I don't call the update() method above.
    update_rects = background_group.draw(screen)
    update_rects += character_group.draw(screen)

    # I always have rects here (even when I don't move any sprites). Why?
    print(update_rects)

    pygame.display.update(update_rects)

    clock.tick(30)
```

Also, is this the correct way to get updated rects from 2 sprite groups?

```
update_rects = background_group.draw(screen)
update_rects += character_group.draw(screen)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't the draw() method only supposed to return rects that have been changed?

No it is not. [`pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates.draw). does not validate the content of the redraw areas or compare pixels, because that would cost too much time. The method collects only the areas that are redrawn, even if they are redrawn with the same content. This is because every `Group.draw()` causes `Group.clear()`. See the documentation of [`pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates.draw):

> Draws all the Sprites to the surface, the same as Group.draw(). This method also returns a list of Rectangular areas on the screen that have been changed. **The returned changes include areas of the screen that have been affected by previous Group.clear() calls.**

You must care about that and avoid redrawing of objects that have not changed. One way I can think of is to put each sprite that has been moved and needs to be updated into an "update" group, and then draw only that group. In case of minimize/restore the entire scene must be redrawn, but in this case performance does not matter.

Comment: So does that mean I need to call the draw() method only 1 time if I'm not animating it (if it's not moving)? If so, the issue is: if I minimize the pygame window and restore it again, the screen won't show the game because I only called draw() once. I'm still confused about when to call the draw() method and when not to call it.

Comment: @garlic I didn't say you had to do that. Nowadays it's so common to redraw the entire scene in every frame. I would leave it as it is. Or is the performance that bad?

Comment: It's a new project I'm working on; I'm pre-optimizing, trying to make it update the screen the most efficient way it could before I dive deeper into the sprite movements/animations. It will probably work fine if I update the whole screen, I'm just thinking maybe one of my users will be using an old computer that is slow.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to put each sprite that has been moved and needs to be updated into an "update" group and then draw only that group. In case of minimize/restore the entire scene must be redrawn, but in this case performance does not matter.